# Static initialization for structs extending structs

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find a way to statically initialize a struct which extends another struct.

If I have a struct in c++:

```
struct aStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

I can statically initialize an instance of this with:

```
aStruct aStructInst = { 1, 2 };
```

I can also extend this struct if I want a child object to store additional information:

```
struct bStruct : aStruct {
    int c;
};
```

Is there any way to statically initialize an instance of `bStruct`?  I've tried a few variations but no luck yet.  Static initialization is important in my use-case to keep (all of) the data out of RAM, which is very limited (embedded application).

Comment: If your compiler supports C++11 constant expressions, you could try a `constexpr` constructor. It also allows *constant initialization*, which is part of *static initialization*.

Comment: Another possibility in C++14 is to use a `constexpr` function where you build the struct (possibly using assignments to the data members) and return it, relying on the (implicit) `constexpr`iveness of the implicitly created copy/move constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using "aggregate initialization" but a class with a base class cannot be an aggregate, so you cannot use aggregate initialization.

As the comment above says, if you add a suitable constructor then you can use the same syntax:

```
struct bStruct : aStruct {
    constexpr bStruct(int a, int b, int c) : aStruct{a, b}, c(c) { }
    int c;
};
```

(You don't need a constructor for `aStruct` because that is still an aggregate so can still be initialized directly using aggregate initialization).

Comment: would this guarantee static initialization?

Comment: @Slava It doesn't *guarantee* static init in general, but it *allows* static init. If the entity you're initializing with this constructor is a non-local variable, and the constructor arguments are all constant expressions, *then* it does guarantee static init. It is also very likely that it performs static init of local static variables, if the arguments are constant expressions.

Comment: Also, if you say `constexpr bStruct b{ 1, 2, 3 };` that guarantees static init even if it's a local variable ... but then the object is const and can't be modified later, which might not be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a constructor in bStruct like this:

`bStruct(int a, int b, int c) : aStruct{a, b}, c(c) {}`

This will initialize aStruct and the c field.

Note: This is c++11 code.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int a; int b;
};
struct B : A
{
    //c++ 0x
    B(int a, int b, int c) : A{ a, b }, c(c) 
    {}
    int c;
};
int main()
{
    B b{ 1,2,3 };
    cout << b.a << b.b << b.c << endl;
}
```

Comment: I am afraid you are missing the point, he wants static initialization